# Swift: Completion handlers and singletons

Tags: swift, singleton, instances, completionhandler

I am trying to use a completion handler to return information from a func. The function is in a class, and I use a singleton to be able to create an instance of the class so I can call the function. For some reason, I can get access to the completionhandler when I am using a singleton.

```
class load {
    static let class = Class()
}

load.class.function(//The completion handler should appear here but doesn't)
```

Comment: That code sample is too abstract. What completion handler are you talking about?

Comment: @luk2302 I have a function in a different class that needs to return information, so I have a completion handler, so when the function is done running it will return the information I need. To access the function, I have a singleton. But when I try to call the function through the singleton, for example: 'load.class.function()'. Between () Xcode should automatically say completion handler because the function I am referencing had a completion handler. Sorry, if that is a bit confusing, I am new to Swift.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd suggest avoiding terms like `class` and `Class` for names for properties or classes. Also, the `load` should be capitalized. Perhaps `class SingletonManager { static let sharedObjectA = ObjectA() ... }` or something like that...

Comment: While appzYourLife's example is the prototypical singleton pattern, you can use your pattern with completion handlers, too. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/7c13073e7b784664b7c0fc0b2807e80f. Bottom line, you need to give us a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem if we're going to help you more.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you define a `Singleton` with a method and a completion handler in Swift

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private init() { }

    func retrieveTheAnswer(completion: (answer:Int) -> ()) {
        completion(answer: 42)
    }
}
```

And this is how you use it

```
Singleton.sharedInstance.retrieveTheAnswer { (answer) in
    print(answer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`class` (Don't call is this!) is only accessible from within the `load` (Don't call it this either!) class:

```
load.class.function()
```